# Reverse scrolling is not working in Xubuntu 23.04 with Chrome

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, touchpad

I have just now installed Xubuntu 23.04, updated the system and installed my wifi and Nvidia drivers, but I'm facing a issue. Even after enabling reverse scrolling in the settings, reverse scrolling is not working in Chrome but it is working in Firefox.

[image: screenshot]

It is also not working in Synaptic package manager, etc.